# Kinect shuts down after running this code and gives error

Tags: python, python-2.7, kinect, pykinect

I'm trying to run the following code,

```
from pykinect import nui
from pykinect.nui import JointId
from pykinect.nui import SkeletonTrackingState
from pykinect.nui import TransformSmoothParameters
with nui.Runtime() as kinect:
    kinect.skeleton_frame_ready+=skeleton_frame_ready
    kinect.skeleton_engine.enable=True
    while True:
        frame= kinect.skeleton_engine.get_next_frame()
        for skeleton in frame.SkeletonData:
            def skeleton_fram_raedy(skeleton_frame):
                for index,data in enumerate(skeleton):
                   if skeleton.eTrackingState==nui.SkeletonTrackingState.TRACKED:
                        head=data.SkeletonPositions[JointId.Head]
                        print head
```

but Kinect shuts down and gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sayyed javed ahmed\Desktop\Humaira\Practice Codes-Python\skeletonnew.py", line 5, in <module>
    with nui.Runtime() as kinect:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pykinect\nui\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.camera = Camera(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pykinect\nui\__init__.py", line 352, in __init__
    self.elevation_angle
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pykinect\nui\__init__.py", line 359, in get_elevation_angle
    return self.runtime._nui.NuiCameraElevationGetAngle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pykinect\nui\_interop.py", line 200, in NuiCameraElevationGetAngle
    _NuiInstance._NuiCameraElevationGetAngle(self, ctypes.byref(res))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 950, in GetResult
WindowsError: [Error -2147024883] The data is invalid
```

I'm new to PyKinect so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are typos in your code. You're assigning a callback to `skeleton_frame_ready` function in `kinect.skeleton_frame_ready+=skeleton_frame_ready`, but have defined it as `def skeleton_fram_raedy(skeleton_frame)`.

Secondly, I think your indentation is off, you have a function definition in a for loop in a while loop:

```
while True:
    frame= kinect.skeleton_engine.get_next_frame()
    for skeleton in frame.SkeletonData:
        def skeleton_fram_raedy(skeleton_frame):
        ...
```

Try something like this:

```
from pykinect import nui
from pykinect.nui import JointId
from pykinect.nui import SkeletonTrackingState
from pykinect.nui import TransformSmoothParameters

def skeleton_frame_ready(skeleton_frame):
    for skeleton in frame.SkeletonData:
        if skeleton.eTrackingState==nui.SkeletonTrackingState.TRACKED:
            for index,data in enumerate(skeleton):
                head=data.SkeletonPositions[JointId.Head]
                print head

with nui.Runtime() as kinect:
    kinect.skeleton_frame_ready+=skeleton_frame_ready
    kinect.skeleton_engine.enable=True
    while True:
        frame= kinect.skeleton_engine.get_next_frame()
```

Thirdly, the error indicates that invalid argument is passed to nui for the kinect camera angle. Not sure why that is. You could try setting the elevation angle to 0 right after initializing nui:

```
with nui.Runtime() as kinect:
    kinect.camera.elevation_angle = 0
    kinect.skeleton_frame_ready+=skeleton_frame_ready
```